# Checking If A Person's Birthday is after a specific date in Microsoft Excel 2003

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

How can I check if a person's birthday is after the 15th of any month in MS Excel 2003? If the birthday is after the 15th, then the first date of the next month should be displayed. If it's before the 15th, then the first date of that month should be displayed.

Comment: use day() function to get the day

Comment: ok. and what logic for the other part?

Answer (score 4):

> =DATE(YEAR(A1);IF(DAY(A1)<=15;MONTH(A1);MONTH(A1)+1); 1)

you may have to substitute comma to semicolon, depending on your locale

(it is very convenient that the function DATE could take month=13 and increment the year)

Answer (score 2):

Be careful at the end of the year!

=MONTH("31.12.2013") + 1 will return 13!

Better you use the EOMONTH function. 
Assuming the The bithday date is stored in D9:

=IF(DAY(D9)<=15;EOMONTH(D9;-1) + 1;EOMONTH(D9;0)+1)

Comment: 13 isn't a problem within MONTH function - Excel happily accepts =DATE(2012,13,1) - that's equivalent to 1st Jan **2013**

Answer (score 1):

Could be like this:

```
 =IF(DAY(A1)>15;DATE(YEAR(TODAY());MONTH(A1)+1;1);DATE(YEAR(TODAY());MONTH(A1);1))
```

The birthday date is in `A1`.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what should happen if birthday is exactly 15th? Next month or this month? Either way you can subtract 15 and then find the end of the month and add 1, i.e. using EOMONTH function

`=EOMONTH(A1-15,0)+1`

or avoiding EOMONTH (because it requires Analysis ToolPak in Excel 2003) you can use

`=DATE(YEAR(A1-15),MONTH(A1-15)+1,1)`

If birthday is on 15th both of those will give current month - if it should be next month for exactly 15th then change instances of -15 in formulas to -14